# Wordpress 5.3 tinymce 5 insert image has no upload / filepicker button

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am using wordpress 5.3.1 and installed Tinymce Advanced 5.3 my problem is as shown in the image there is no button to select an image source when the user wants to insert an image in their text.
[image: no button to select an image source]

Comment: Did you try asking the developer of said plugin about this already? > [TinyMCE Advanced Support Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/tinymce-advanced/).

Comment: Can you show us a relevant piece of code? for ex. the plugin core